# How can I sort IP addresses stored as varchar2 in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I sort numerical IP addresses stored as varchar2? I would the addresses to sort in "natural" numerical order rather than lexicographical order (e.g. '1.1.1.9' before '1.1.1.10').

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_replace` to pad each octet with leading zeroes so that
`1.1.1.9` will be transformed to `001.001.001.009`.

```
create table t (a varchar2(16));
insert into t values('10.1.1.1');
insert into t values('10.1.1.9');
insert into t values('10.1.1.10');

select * from t order by regexp_replace(regexp_replace(a,'(\d+)','00\1'),'0*(\d{3})','\1');

a
-
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.9
10.1.1.10
```

If performance is a consideration you can consider creating a function-based index or converting the IP address to a number before storing it.

```
create index ix on t (regexp_replace(regexp_replace(a,'(\d+)','00\1'),'0*(\d{3})','\1'));
```

Comment: It would be more faster to use usual `replace` for zero-padding `replace('.'||a,'.','.00')` instead of regexp counterpart `regexp_replace(a,'(\d+)','00\1')`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which translate it to a decimal number:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Ip2Decimal(IP IN VARCHAR2) RETURN INTEGER DETERMINISTIC IS
    DecimalIp INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    IF Ip IS NULL THEN 
        RETURN NULL; 
    END IF;
    FOR i IN 1..4 LOOP
        DecimalIp := DecimalIp + REGEXP_SUBSTR(IP, '\d+', 1, i) * 256**(4-i);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN DecimalIp;
END Ip2Decimal;
```

Then sort by this function value. A function-based-index should be usefull in this case.